# URL rewrite magento 2 admin-side issue

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, category-tree

Magento2 - facing issue with below error in admin panel

error in console

category:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 473

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getData (main.js:58)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Object.apply (main.js:74)
at HTMLDocument.bootstrap (bootstrap.js:106)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
```

Comment: may be something issue for command line, try to put basic commands.

Comment: HI, @AnasMansuri can you please explain in brief.

Comment: are you facing only in category page or every pages ?

Comment: hi @AnasMansuri I facing the error the only URL rewrite page in category   
https://prnt.sc/p3ravt please check-in this shot

Comment: are you facing issue after data migration ?

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: hey guys issue is short out now thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Add in you current layout catalog_product_view.xml :

```
<referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi Pratik I try this but still issue